# How do i make javascript react to the windows width?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
function mobileMenu() {
 document.getElementById("my_nav_menu").style.cssText = "padding: 0 26px 26px 26px; height: 530px;";
 document.getElementById("the_overlay").style.cssText = "visibility: visible; opacity: .3;";
 document.getElementById("the_clicker").style.cssText = "opacity: 0; visibility: hidden; display: none;";
 document.getElementById("the_closer").style.cssText = "opacity: 1; visibility: visible; display: block;";
}

function closeMenu() {
 document.getElementById("my_nav_menu").style.cssText = "padding: 0; height: 0;";
 document.getElementById("the_overlay").style.cssText = "visibility: hidden; opacity: 0;";
 document.getElementById("the_clicker").style.cssText = "opacity: 1; visibility: visible;";
 document.getElementById("the_closer").style.cssText = "opacity: 0; visibility: hidden;";
}
```

```css
/* Welcome to Compass. Use this file to write IE specific override styles.
 * Import this file using the following HTML or equivalent:
 * <!--[if IE]>
 *   <link href="/stylesheets/ie.css" media="screen, projection" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 * <![endif]--> */


/* Welcome to Compass. Use this file to define print styles.
 * Import this file using the following HTML or equivalent:
 * <link href="/stylesheets/print.css" media="print" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> */


/* Welcome to Compass.
 * In this file you should write your main styles. (or centralize your imports)
 * Import this file using the following HTML or equivalent:
 * <link href="/stylesheets/screen.css" media="screen, projection" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> */
/* line 5, ../../../../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/compass-core-1.0.3/stylesheets/compass/reset/_utilities.scss */
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

/* line 22, ../../../../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/compass-core-1.0.3/stylesheets/compass/reset/_utilities.scss */
html {
  line-height: 1;
}

/* line 24, ../../../../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/compass-core-1.0.3/stylesheets/compass/reset/_utilities.scss */
ol, ul {
  list-style: none;
}

/* line 26, ../../../../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/compass-core-1.0.3/stylesheets/compass/reset/_utilities.scss */
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

/* line 28, ../../../../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/compass-core-1.0.3/stylesheets/compass/reset/_utilities.scss */
caption, th, td {
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: normal;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

/* line 30, ../../../../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/compass-core-1.0.3/stylesheets/compass/reset/_utilities.scss */
q, blockquote {
  quotes: none;
}
/* line 103, ../../../../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/compass-core-1.0.3/stylesheets/compass/reset/_utilities.scss */
q:before, q:after, blockquote:before, blockquote:after {
  content: "";
  content: none;
}

/* line 32, ../../../../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/compass-core-1.0.3/stylesheets/compass/reset/_utilities.scss */
a img {
  border: none;
}

/* line 116, ../../../../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/compass-core-1.0.3/stylesheets/compass/reset/_utilities.scss */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, main, menu, nav, section, summary {
  display: block;
}

/*
 *
 * IMPORTANT OVERS
 *
 */
/* line 7, ../sass/partials/_def.sass */
* {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* line 10, ../sass/partials/_def.sass */
body {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

/*
 *
 * GENERALS
 *
 */
/* line 21, ../sass/partials/_def.sass */
#the_overlay {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  z-index: 900;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  -moz-transition-duration: 500ms;
  -o-transition-duration: 500ms;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 500ms;
  transition-duration: 500ms;
}

/* line 30, ../sass/partials/_def.sass */
.nav_wrap {
  padding: 15px 20px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5em;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 999;
}
/* line 40, ../sass/partials/_def.sass */
.nav_wrap a {
  height: 100%;
  color: inherit;
}
/* line 43, ../sass/partials/_def.sass */
.nav_wrap a #main_logo {
  transition: 300ms;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
/* line 47, ../sass/partials/_def.sass */
.nav_wrap a #main_logo:hover {
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

/* line 50, ../sass/partials/_def.sass */
#my_nav_menu {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-end;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  height: 1em;
  -moz-transition-duration: 400ms;
  -o-transition-duration: 400ms;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 400ms;
  transition-duration: 400ms;
}
/* line 58, ../sass/partials/_def.sass */
#my_nav_menu .my_nav_links {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  font: 900 0.9em "Arial", sans-serif;
  margin: 0 8px;
  transition: 300ms;
}
/* line 64, ../sass/partials/_def.sass */
#my_nav_menu .my_nav_links:hover {
  color: red;
}
/* line 67, ../sass/partials/_def.sass */
#my_nav_menu .drop-wrap {
  height: 20px;
  height: 3em;
  position: relative;
}
/* line 71, ../sass/partials/_def.sass */
#my_nav_menu .drop-wrap:hover > .dropper {
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 1.9em;
  height: auto;
}
/* line 76, ../sass/partials/_def.sass */
#my_nav_menu .drop-wrap .dropper {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  width: 10em;
  background-color: gold;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 300ms;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  height: 0;
}
/* line 88, ../sass/partials/_def.sass */
#my_nav_menu .drop-wrap .dropper .drops {
  padding: 5px 8px;
  margin: 0;
}

/*
 *
 * THE BURGER
 *
 */
/* line 99, ../sass/partials/_def.sass */
._burger {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
  -moz-transition-duration: 200ms;
  -o-transition-duration: 200ms;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 200ms;
  transition-duration: 200ms;
}

/* line 104, ../sass/partials/_def.sass */
._closewin {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
  -moz-transition-duration: 300ms;
  -o-transition-duration: 300ms;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 300ms;
  transition-duration: 300ms;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  /*
   *
   * GENERALS
   *
   */
  /* line 116, ../sass/partials/_def.sass */
  .nav_wrap {
    width: 100%;
    height: 5em;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
    justify-content: space-between;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  /* line 122, ../sass/partials/_def.sass */
  .nav_wrap a {
    height: 100%;
    color: inherit;
  }
  /* line 125, ../sass/partials/_def.sass */
  .nav_wrap a #main_logo {
    transition: 300ms;
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
  }
  /* line 129, ../sass/partials/_def.sass */
  .nav_wrap a #main_logo:hover {
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }

  /* line 132, ../sass/partials/_def.sass */
  #my_nav_menu {
    display: block;
    background-color: lightblue;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
    right: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 0;
    width: 210px;
    z-index: 999;
  }
  /* line 143, ../sass/partials/_def.sass */
  #my_nav_menu .my_nav_links {
    margin: 6px;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    height: auto;
  }
  /* line 149, ../sass/partials/_def.sass */
  #my_nav_menu .drop-wrap {
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
  }
  /* line 152, ../sass/partials/_def.sass */
  #my_nav_menu .drop-wrap:hover > .dropper {
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    height: auto;
  }
  /* line 157, ../sass/partials/_def.sass */
  #my_nav_menu .drop-wrap .dropper {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
  }
  /* line 164, ../sass/partials/_def.sass */
  #my_nav_menu .drop-wrap .dropper .drops {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 6px;
  }

  /*
   *
   * THE BURGER
   *
   */
  /* line 175, ../sass/partials/_def.sass */
  ._burger {
    display: block;
  }

  /* line 178, ../sass/partials/_def.sass */
  ._closewin {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
  <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags-->
  <!--meta(http-equiv='refresh' content='1')-->
  <title>strangeNav</title>
  <!-- THAT SASSY SHIT-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/style.css">
  <!-- FONT AWESOME-->
  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/7997cedcfb.js"></script>
  <script src="javascripts/nav.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="the_overlay" onclick="closeMenu()"></div>
  <div class="nav_wrap"><a href="#"><img id="main_logo" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"></a>
    <div id="my_nav_menu"><a class="my_nav_links" href="#">Explore</a>
      
      <div class="drop-wrap"><a class="my_nav_links" href="#">Eat</a>
        <div class="dropper"><a class="my_nav_links drops" href="#">Brunch</a><a class="my_nav_links drops" href="#">Lunch</a><a class="my_nav_links drops" href="#">Dinner</a></div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="drop-wrap"><a class="my_nav_links" href="#">Play</a>
        <div class="dropper"><a class="my_nav_links drops" href="#">Art</a><a class="my_nav_links drops" href="#">Museums</a><a class="my_nav_links drops" href="#">Parks</a></div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="drop-wrap"><a class="my_nav_links" href="#">Nightlife</a>
        <div class="dropper"><a class="my_nav_links drops" href="#">Bars</a><a class="my_nav_links drops" href="#">Clubs</a></div>
      </div>
      <a class="my_nav_links" href="#">History</a>
      <a class="my_nav_links" href="#">Tours</a>
      <a class="my_nav_links" href="#">Video</a>
      <a class="my_nav_links" href="#">Shop</a>
      <a class="my_nav_links" href="#">About</a>
      <a class="my_nav_links" href="#">Contact</a>
    </div><i class="fa fa-bars _burger" id="the_clicker" aria-hidden="true" onclick="mobileMenu()"></i><i class="fa fa-times _closewin" id="the_closer" aria-hidden="true" onclick="closeMenu()"></i>
  </div>
</body>
```

This is my first script. It's extremely basic but it somewhat serves my purpose for now. I know this script is extremely noob-status but like i said, it serves my purpose. My question is: is there a smoother way to do what im trying to do?

By the way, i DO NOT WANT JQUERY... nothing against it, i use it all the time. But im trying to learn javascript... at least enough to make my websites a bit more snazzy...

The problem im having is EVERYTHING works the way i want it to for mobile and tablet. but when i resize my browser window, the styles on the nav menu do not revert back to there desktop version...

in other words: on tablet and mobile id like to have the nav menu be 0px in height, but when the browser resizes to desktop i need the nav menu to go back to being 1em in height...

The snippet i added is what i currently have but i have tried tons of things i saw online. I fear im just not saying what it is that i actually need correctly.... thoughts anyone?

Comment: JavaScript is entirely the wrong thing for this. Use CSS media queries.

Comment: To answer your question directly, [you *can* handle resize events in js](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onresize), but as the previous two comments state, you should almost definitely be using CSS media queries for this.

Comment: For reference, see [Using media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) and [Responsive design](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Progressive/Responsive).

Comment: So... im a designer first. I self taught (me) css3 html pug and sass because thats all i ever needed for our clients. Then wordpress came about and i started in on PHP... kind of skipped javascript. so first im sorry for the somewhat sloppy code lol.

Comment: having said that: the issue i had with using css only. 1: when i click the hamburger icon, nothing is smooth. both the overlay, and the mobile menu would sort of JUMP from one state to another instead of taking 500ms like i had. nothing was smooth until i implemented the script, albeit an admittedly sloppy one lol. the only difference is in the original sass i used transition: 500ms; instead of transition-duration: 500ms.... could that be the mistake i made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is my update. Did not have a chance to get to this till now. this actually worked for me. as i said before, although i can do this in css, i need it to resize dynamically. This did the trick. However, I'm still open to any suggestions on a cleaner way o do this?

```js
function mobileMenu() {
 document.getElementById("my_nav_menu").style.cssText = "padding: 0 26px 26px 26px; height: 530px;";
 document.getElementById("the_overlay").style.cssText = "visibility: visible; opacity: .3;";
 document.getElementById("the_clicker").style.cssText = "opacity: 0; visibility: hidden; display: none;";
 document.getElementById("the_closer").style.cssText = "opacity: 1; visibility: visible; display: block;";
}


function closeMenu() {
 //Making sure the styles properly reset for Dynamic Resizing
 if (window.innerWidth < 800) {
  document.getElementById("my_nav_menu").style.cssText = "padding: 0; height: 0;";
  document.getElementById("the_overlay").style.cssText = "visibility: hidden; opacity: 0;";
  document.getElementById("the_clicker").style.cssText = "opacity: 1; visibility: visible;";
  document.getElementById("the_closer").style.cssText = "opacity: 0; visibility: hidden;";
 }
  // For desktop
 else {
  document.getElementById("my_nav_menu").style.cssText = "padding: 0; height: 1em;";
  document.getElementById("the_clicker").style.cssText = "opacity: 0; visibility: hidden;";
 }
}
```